# 3D Touch freezes my APP

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch

Maybe my problema is equals to:

[Force Touch animation freezes if gently touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557823/force-touch-animation-freezes-if-gently-touched)

[App is freezing in 'peek and pop' implementation in iPhone 6s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934956/app-is-freezing-in-peek-and-pop-implementation-in-iphone-6s)

1) Forces-touches without "bug":
An `UITransitionView` layer is created to preview my View Controller. It works perfectly.

[image]

2) Forces-touches with "bug":
When I gently tap over the button, the `UITransitionView` layer is created but its transparent (without content) and at this point I can't interact with my app (because the top layer is "empty").

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Code:

`HomeViewController`

```
extension HomeViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            previewingContext.sourceRect = balanceButton!.bounds
        }

        let balanceViewController = UIStoryboard.balanceViewController()
        balanceViewController.delegate = self
        balanceViewController.account = account
        balanceViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 118)
        navigationController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 118)

        return balanceViewController
    }

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        let balanceViewController = viewControllerToCommit as! BalanceViewController
        balanceViewController.shouldPresentCompleteMode = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(balanceViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

On `BalanceViewController`:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
        let action2 = UIPreviewAction(title: "Últimos 5 dias úteis", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) in
           self.delegate?.balanceViewControllerFilterDidSelected(.FiveDays)
        }
        let action3 = UIPreviewAction(title: "action", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) in
            self.delegate?.balanceViewControllerFilterDidSelected(.FiftyDays)
        }
        let action4 = UIPreviewAction(title: "action", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) in
            self.delegate?.balanceViewControllerFilterDidSelected(.ThirtyDays)
        }
        let action5 = UIPreviewAction(title: "action", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) in
            self.delegate?.balanceViewControllerFilterDidSelected(.SixtyDays)
        }

        return [action2, action3, action4, action5]
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

When I switch to another app and switch back to my app.. my device vibrates and peeks, but freezes again.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You should answer your question _as an answer_, not as an edit to the question! Answering your own question is perfectly legal on SO.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I've found the solution. The problem was a "redundant" Peek and Pop registration. I was registering:

1) Call `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)` on `viewDidLoad()`

2) [image]

Maybe they conflict with each other and to solve this I've deleted the storyboard segue.